# How to parse serializer data in django rest framework

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkcmx.png)

I want to parse this so that i can get a list of phase id to run another query for specific reason. this is serializer.data Response.
how to parse this to get a list of ids ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the array from the image is stored in `myArray`:

`result = [item["phase_id"] for item in myArray]`